# Fitting regime switching model to binary time series

Tags: time-series, fitting

I have a binary time series $X_t$ that I'd like to fit.  It clearly has long memory effects (high Hurst exponent), and I believe that it is generated by a Bernoulli process where the probability shifts in discrete jumps:

$$
U_t = 
\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
U_{t-1} \text{ w.p. } p \\
N(0, \sigma) \text{ w.p. } 1-p \\
\end{array}
\right. \\
X_t = Bernoulli(Probit(U_t))
$$

What is a good way to fit $\sigma$ and $p$ to my data?  I thought I could use MCMC with something like Stan, but I don't see a way to model the switching behavior of the latent variable $U_t$.